# Unable to lookup 'placedorder' on Restaurants or RestrauntsAdmin

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

*My error :*

**Unable to lookup 'placedorder' on Restaurants or RestrauntsAdmin**
i am getting this error in admin panel, i havent entered any data in placed order yet and neither in restaurants

```
class Restaurants(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mob_no = models.IntegerField()
    opening_time = models.TimeField()
    closing_time = models.TimeField()
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='restraunts/cover')


 # Create your models here.
    class PlacedOrder(models.Model):
        order_id= models.CharField(max_length=255)
        restraunt = models.ForeignKey(to='restaurants.Restaurants', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        order_time = models.TimeField(
            auto_now_add=True)
        estimated_delivery_time = models.TimeField()
        actual_delivery_time = models.TimeField()
        food_ready_time = models.TimeField()
        total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
```

updated :
**orders admin**

```
class PlacedOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = [field.name for field in PlacedOrder._meta.get_fields()]
    list_display = [field.name for field in PlacedOrder._meta.get_fields()]


admin.site.register(InOrder)
admin.site.register(PlacedOrder,PlacedOrderAdmin)
admin.site.register(Comment)
admin.site.register(Status)
```

**Restaurants admin**

```
class RestrauntsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = [field.name for field in Restaurants._meta.get_fields()]
    list_display =  [field.name for field in Restaurants._meta.get_fields()]


class CityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['city_name','zip_code']
    list_display= ('city_name','zip_code')

admin.site.register(Restaurants,RestrauntsAdmin)
admin.site.register(City,CityAdmin)
```

Comment: Can you please share the corresponding `ModelAdmin`?

Comment: Can you please share your admin.poy file code?

Comment: i have updated my snippett

Comment: @AtifShafi: it seems that you do not use your `PlacedOrderAdmin`, you only register with `admin.site.register(PlacedOrder)`, so that meanst it will use the "default" `ModelAdmin` for that model.

Comment: I used it but it is still showing the same error,